# Adding rows to dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list (`xlist`) of empty dataframes `x0:x10`. I also have populated dataframe `y` (about 13,000 rows). All dataframes have the number of columns and column headers.

```
 y  Date  Time  Correct  Incorrect  Average  Score  EC  E1?  E2?  E3?
[1] 10/1  1:14     8         2         15     80    0   y    n    y
[2] 10/2  8:45     5         5         12     50    1   n    y    y
```

I'm trying to copy each row of `y` into one of the dataframes in `xlist`.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
    xlist(paste0("x",y[i,3])) <- rbind(xlist(paste0("x",y[i,3])), y[i,]))
}
```

Basically, based on the number in the "correct" column, I want to copy that row into the corresponding dataframe in `xlist` (so the first row to `x8`, the second to `x5`).

The problem with the list of dataframes is that it's not reading them as dataframes here

```
> class(xlist[x1])
[1] "list"
```

but it is in the environment panel

```
xlist    list of 11
x0: 'data.frame' 0 obs of 10 variables:
..$ etc
x1: 'data.frame' 0 obs of 10 variables:
..$ etc
etc
```

Using the copy code above throws "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length." A few rewrites have gotten "number of columns of arguments do not match" (not sure how). So I tried creating my own AddRow function  to see if `rbind` was the issue:

```
AddRow <- function(DF,NewRow) {
  DF[nrow(DF) + 1] <- NewRow
  DF
}
```

but it throws an "incorrect # of subscripts in matrix" error.

How can I go about copying all the rows of `y` into corresponding dataframes within `xlist`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out the exact answer, but I came up with a more efficient workaround, since after the iteration I didn't need the list anymore (but rather the actual `x` dataframes themselves). I discovered the sqldf package.

By not using a list of frames at all, I got the list I needed.

```
for (i in 0:10) {
    assign(paste0("x",i),
           sqldf(paste0("select * from y where Correct = ", i)))
}
```

This creates 11 dataframes, named `x0` through `x10`, and each is autopopulated through the SQL query.

Comment: `split(y, y$Correct)` will split data frame `y` into a list of data frames each with a separate value of `Correct`.